# What does the phrase "as it is called" mean?

Tags: phrases

In the below sentence what it the meaning of the phrase "as it is called" ?

```
Life, as it is called, is for most of us one long postponement.
```

Answer (score 2):

Literally, it's relating the label to the ontological reality. The word of four letters ('life') is the label (what it's *called*) applied to *life*, the sequence of events between birth and death - and in the context of the rest of the sentence, focusing on the theme of postponement.

Rhetorically, there's an implication that the sequence of postponements (or their amalgamation into a single long postponement) isn't what one might consider to be full of 'life' or truly 'living'.